# How to get the value from getElementbyId into input box

Tags: javascript, html

I am having this code below

```js
function jsmeOnLoad() {
  document.getElementById("jsme_container").style.display = "none"
  jsmeApplet = new JSApplet.JSME("jsme_container", "380px", "340px", {
    "options": "oldlook,marker,markAtomOnly,nocanonize"
  });        
  jsmeApplet.setCallBack("AfterStructureModified", show_smiles);
}
 
//jsmeApplet.setNotifyStructuralChangeJSfunction("show_smiles");
                
var patt = /\[([A-Za-z][a-z]?)H?\d*:\d+\]/g; //regexp pattern for numbered atom
function show_smiles(event) {
  smiles = event.src.smiles(); //atom that are colored are numbered
  new_smiles = smiles.replace(patt, '<em>$1</em>');
  document.getElementById("smiles_container").value = new_smiles
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter the Solute Molecule here" name="solute" id='smiles_container' ><br> <br>
```

Even though I was calling using `id=smiles_container` I am not getting the out put in input box. please help

Comment: A snippet makes only sense when there's something to execute that helps understanding the question/problem. There's no `JSApplet` so this snippet doesn't help. And if you use a snippet, please also use the _"Tidy"_ feature to fix the format.

Comment: The `.value` attribute doesn't understand html

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add a console.log() in your `show_smiles` function. Nothing is showing for one of these reasons: 1) `show_smiles` is never being called. 2) `new_smiles` is actually empty (your pattern could be broken) so you don't see a change 3) You have an error so `show_smiles` never finishes. 4) `new_smiles` is some how not a string which the input is expecting.

Comment: I think the `smiles_container` id is interfering with another id. doing  `document.getElementById("smiles").value = new_smiles` rectified my problem